# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_site': when AWS CodePipeline (GitHub) deploy to Elastic Beanstalk (Django)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gunicorn, aws-codepipeline

I've been stuck on this problem for 3 weeks. I've connected my GitHub to AWS CodePipeline and AWS CodePipeline is trying to deploy the code to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I keep getting the same error and can't figure out the solution.

[image: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Error]

My ProcFile:

```
web: gunicorn my_site.wsgi:application
```

My file structure:

```
-- .ebextensions
    -- django.config
-- ProcFile
-- tq_django
    -- my_site
        -- wsgi.py
```

My wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/app/current/tq_django/my_site')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_site.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My django.config within .ebextensions

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: my_site.wsgi:application
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: my_site.settings
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /tq: static
```

Comment: you mentioned `my_site` in installed_apps right in `settings.py`?

Comment: @HemalPatel I just added my_site to installed_apps and I am getting the same error